# How to add values from two different functions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

In my case, I found the value of 2 different sums in two different functions. Now all I need to do is subtract these two values but I am not sure if it is possible to do so from two different functions. What would be the best way to perform this?

```
function networth()
{
   var totNoA = document.getElementsByName("number4[]").length;
   var sum = 0;

   for(var i=0; i<totNoA; i++)
   {
      sum +=parseInt(document.getElementsByName("number4[]")[i].value);
      console.log(sum);
   }
}
```

Here I have the variable 'sum' that has a value.

```
function networth1()
{
   var totNoL = document.getElementsByName("number5[]").length;
   var sumL = 0;

   for(var x=0; x<totNoL; x++)
   {
      sumL +=parseInt(document.getElementsByName("number5[]")[x].value);
      console.log(sumL);

      sum - sumL = total_sum;
      document.Net_worth.total1.value = total_sum;
   }
}
```

I would like to subtract sum - sumL but I am not doing it right. Any thoughts?

Comment: You should use `parseInt(x, 10)` instead of `parseInt(x)`.

Comment: What is your expected output? And what is your actual output? [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also return **sum** from **networth** function like this :

```
function networth()
{
   var totNoA = document.getElementsByName("number4[]").length;
   var sum = 0;

   for(var i=0; i<totNoA; i++)
   {
      sum +=parseInt(document.getElementsByName("number4[]")[i].value);
      console.log(sum);
   }
   return sum; 
}
```

And then you can use it's value in your **networth1** function, like below :

```
function networth1()
{
   var totNoL = document.getElementsByName("number5[]").length;
   var sumL = 0;

   for(var x=0; x<totNoL; x++)
   {
      sumL +=parseInt(document.getElementsByName("number5[]")[x].value);
      console.log(sumL);    
   }
      var sum = networth();
      total_sum = sum - sumL;
      document.Net_worth.total1.value = total_sum;
}
```

You don't need to calculate difference inside loop as you are requiring only the final difference. Also you can follow what other has suggested here. Make **sum** and **sumL** global variables instead of making them local.

Comment: It worked. So when you return a value and want to call for it later, you just assign that values variable to its function? (var sum = networth();) that is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `sum` and `sumL` in the global scope. Move `var sum = 0` and `var sumL = 0` outside of the functions, and get their difference using `sum-sumL`.

Answer (score 0):

These functions should return the sum values and write one more function that performs subtraction using values returned by these functions 
Note :write the functions small n self explainable it improves code maintainability

Comment: So are you suggesting just leaving these two functions the way they are and creating another function that subtracts sum - sumL?

Comment: Yes move the  code(  total_sum=sum - sumL;
      document.Net_worth.total1.value = total_sum;) to new function 

      

and the above functions should return sum and sumL values

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you do two searches in the DOM with `document.getElementsByName` in each function, but this is not needed.

Simplifying your own code, it would look like this:

```
function netWorth(query) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByName(query);
    var sum = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(elements[i].value);
    }

    return sum; 
}

var sum = netWorth("number4[]");
var sumL = netWorth("number5[]");

document.Net_worth.total1.value = (sum - sumL);
```